# How to get "media id" from media "image name/path" drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have created image field on media content type and then created media reference field in article node.

I want to retrieve the media id from image path.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can get the media id from filename

```
// Load file by filename
// array.
$file = $this->entityTypeManager
  ->getStorage('file')
  ->loadByProperties(['filename' => $file_name]);

// Get First file (make a loop if you get many files)
$fileId = array_shift($file)->fid->value;

// Array of Medias witch contains your file.
$this->entityTypeManager
  ->getStorage('media')
  ->loadByProperties(['field_media_image' => $fileId]);
```

Comment: And then each from each $media element in that array you can simply do: $media->id()